# Cassandra one or nodes UNREACHABLE

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

I have 4 or 5 nodes in one DC, when I run command on below nodes:

bin/nodetool describecluster

Cluster Information:
    Name: xxx
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        b339c963-f74f-3d14-8a3f-a9bf8a5b613c: [172.16.4.134, 172.16.4.135, 172.16.4.137]

```
    UNREACHABLE: [172.16.4.136]
```

Cluster Information:
    Name: xxx
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        b339c963-f74f-3d14-8a3f-a9bf8a5b613c: [172.16.4.134, 172.16.4.135, 172.16.4.137]

```
    UNREACHABLE: [172.16.4.136]
```

To find out that: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/troubleshooting/cassandra/schemaDisagree.html

Restart all the nodes. That 's fine. But problem still appears after 5 ỏ 10minutes..., and we cannot connect the nodes one by one. The application has appear read timeout, not response to app.

In fact , we have a application to select (by primary key) & insert records) , using  Datastax Java driver.

read_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000

range_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000

write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000

So how to deal with that? Thanks you

Comment: Try clearing the storage folder of [172.16.4.136] node and check the seeds are configured correctly and start the node

Comment: include version. I would assume that `172.16.4.136` isnt accessible on port 7000 from the other nodes in cluster.

Comment: Cassandra 3.9. Telnet 7000 from other nodes are to .136 are ok.

Comment: Already clear storage .136 and try format all of nodes. But This problem still appear. It has problem one by one   UNREACHABLE: [172.16.4.134, 172.16.4.136, 172.16.4.137]

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs (in the 10min after the restart)?

Comment: No error log nevsv, I 've already change from GosshipSnitch to SimpleSnitch and increase phi_convict_threshold = 12. That's not resolve problem..